# Find the Second highest date set in a query

Tags: ms-access

can anyone help me solve this problem I am having. In our database we view our most recent cost prices for every product we offer by Querying for the max data (EffDt) for that product, below:

```
In (
    SELECT MAX(B.EffDt) AS MaxOfDt 
    FROM tblProductCost AS B 
    WHERE tblProductCost.ProductID = B.ProductID AND      
          tblProductCost.CntWght   = B.CntWght AND  
          tblProductCost.OriginID  = B.OriginID AND  
          tblProductCost.UOMID     = B.UOMID AND 
          B.EffDt <= Date()
)
```

However want to run a comparison and look at what would be the second to last price was the second highest date. 
I hope I have expend this all right and I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or solutions that anyone could offer.

Answer (score 0):

You use:

```
In (SELECT Top 2 B.EffDt AS MaxOfDt FROM tblProductCost AS B WHERE  tblProductCost.ProductID=B.ProductID AND tblProductCost.CntWght=B.CntWght AND  tblProductCost.OriginID=B.OriginID AND tblProductCost.UOMID=B.UOMID AND B.EffDt <= Date() ORDER BY B.EffDt Desc)
```

Comment: Thank You, this is a great help.